# let vs member in F#, need to clarify something

Tags: f#

Let's consider the following code:

```
type RulesStore() =

    ...
    static member LoadAsync : Async<RulesStore> =
        async {
            let! r = Startup.States.GetAsStringAsync("rules") |> Async.AwaitTask

            return
                if String.IsNullOrEmpty r then
                    new RulesStore()
                else
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RulesStore>(r);
        }
```

This is a static method inside an object and is used to get an instance of that object, either from a stored json, or a new clean one.

Am I right to believe that if I replace:

> static member LoadAsync : Async =

with

> let LoadAsync : Async =

LoadAsync would be evaluated once and subsequent loads would return the same result? if I am wrong, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more subtle. First, you are comparing `let` (instance) with `static member` (static), which adds the obvious difference between things that happen for each instance and things that are shared by all instances.

A more useful comparison is to compare regular `member` and `let`. The subtle thing is that `async` computations are themselves delayed, so they only run body when you execute them.

The following is a sample to illustrate this - I added one `printf` before the definition of `async` and one inside the `async` block, for both `let` and `member`:

```
type A() = 
  let test = 
    printfn "let: before async"
    async { 
      printfn "let: inside async"
    }
  member x.Test =
    printfn "member: before async"
    async { 
      printfn "member: inside async"
    }
  member x.RunLet() = test |> Async.RunSynchronously
  member x.RunMember() = x.Test |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Here is what the code does:

```
let a = A() 
// prints "let: before async"
a.RunLet()  
// prints "let: inside async"
a.RunLet()  
// prints "let: inside async"
a.RunMember()  
// prints "member: before async"
// and "member: inside async"
a.RunMember()  
// prints "member: before async"
// and "member: inside async"
```

As you can see, the code "inside async" runs repeatedly each time you invoke the async computation. However, the code "before async" runs only once for `let` and repeatedly for `member`.

In reality, you almost never have code before async, so this does not make much difference in typical uses, but there is some difference - with `let`, the async computation is constructed just once and then reused each time.

Comment: ok, so that confirms what I was thinking. Thanks for putting out an example that clarifies it!